# Manage insert update scheduled tasks

Tags: spring, postgresql, scheduled-tasks

I'm not used to work with scheduled tasks, I need some advice (**is my thought good or bad**)

I'm designing a function that runs every 20 minutes. This function retrieves data from a json file (which I do not have control over) and inserts the data into the database.

When I was doing this I did not think that this will create a unique ID problem in the database view that it is the same data that updates each time.

I thought of doing two functions:

1: the first insertions (INSERT)

2: Update the data according to the ID (UPDATE)

```
@Component
public class LoadSportsCompetition {

  @PostConstruct
  public void insert() {
    // 1 : get json data
    // 2 : insert in DB
  }

  @Scheduled(cron="0 0/20 * * * ?")
  public void update() {
    // 1 : get json data
    // 2 : update rows by ID      
  }

}
```

Comment: What's your actual *question*?

Comment: I'm just wandering if it's a good or bad way to do

Comment: Which version of PostgreSQL are you using? If using the newer (9.5+) versions, you probably want to use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE ... ;` and perform everything in just one step. See [`INSERT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html)

Comment: Yes, I use a newer one, So even if it's the same id no error will be fired right.

Comment: If there's a primary key conflict (or any other kind of conflict you *specify*), instead of performing the standard `INSERT`, the `UPDATE` part will take place. This update can still generate errors (such as violating `CHECK` or `REFERENCES` constraints, if they exist, or violate some *type* restrictions, such as trying to fit 'hello' into a `char(3)`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (most probably) best way to handle this in PostgreSQL 9.5 and later, is to use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT ... DO UPDATE`.

Let's assume this is your original table (very simple, for the sake of this example):

```
CREATE TABLE tbl
(
    tbl_id INTEGER,
    payload JSONB,

    CONSTRAINT tbl_pk 
       PRIMARY KEY (tbl_id)
) ;
```

We fill it with the starting data:

```
INSERT INTO tbl
   (tbl_id, payload)
VALUES
   (1, '{"a":12}'),
   (2, '{"a":13, "b": 25}'),
   (3, '{"a":15, "b": [12,13,14]}'),
   (4, '{"a":12, "c": "something"}'),
   (5, '{"a":13, "x": 1234.567}'),
   (6, '{"a":12, "x": 1234.789}') ;
```

Now we perform a non-conflicting insert (i.e.: the ON CONFLICT ... DO won't be executed):

```
-- A normal insert, no conflict
INSERT INTO tbl
   (tbl_id, payload)
VALUES
   (7, '{"x": 1234.56, "y": 3456.78}')
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT tbl_pk DO 
UPDATE
   SET payload = excluded.payload ;   -- Note: the excluded pseudo-table comprises the conflicting rows
```

And now we perform one `INSERT` that would generate a `PRIMARY KEY` conflict, which will be handled by the `ON CONFLICT` clause and will perform an update

```
-- A conflicting insert
INSERT INTO tbl
   (tbl_id, payload)
VALUES
   (3, '{"a": 16, "b": "I don''t know"}')
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT tbl_pk DO 
UPDATE
   SET payload = excluded.payload ;
```

And now, a two row insert that will conflict on one row, and insert the other:

```
-- Now one of each
-- A conflicting insert
INSERT INTO tbl
   (tbl_id, payload)
VALUES
   (4, '{"a": 18, "b": "I will we updated"}'),
   (9, '{"a": 17, "b": "I am nuber 9"}')
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT tbl_pk DO UPDATE
   SET payload = excluded.payload ;
```

We check now the table:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY tbl_id ;
```

```
tbl_id | payload                            
-----: | :----------------------------------
     1 | {"a": 12}                          
     2 | {"a": 13, "b": 25}                 
     3 | {"a": 16, "b": "I don't know"}     
     4 | {"a": 18, "b": "I will we updated"}
     5 | {"a": 13, "x": 1234.567}           
     6 | {"a": 12, "x": 1234.789}           
     7 | {"x": 1234.56, "y": 3456.78}       
     9 | {"a": 17, "b": "I am nuber 9"}
```

Your code should loop through your incoming data, get it, and perform all the `INSERT/UPDATE` (sometimes called `MERGE` or `UPSERT`) one row at a time, or in batches, with multi-line `VALUES`.

You can get all the code at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c3a06368ef70c1e708f13bb0ff9f7844)*

---

There is also one alternative, which is better suited if you work in batches. Use a `WITH` statement, that has one `UPDATE` clause, followed by an `INSERT` one:

```
-- Avoiding (most) concurrency issues.

BEGIN TRANSACTION ;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE ;

WITH data_to_load (tbl_id,  payload) AS
(
    VALUES
       (3, '{"a": 16, "b": "I don''t know"}' :: jsonb),
       (4, '{"a": 18, "b": "I will we updated"}'),
       (7, '{"x": 1234.56, "y": 3456.78}'),
       (9, '{"a": 17, "b": "I am nuber 9"}')
), 
update_existing AS
(
    UPDATE
        tbl
    SET 
        payload = data_to_load.payload
    FROM
        data_to_load
    WHERE
        tbl.tbl_id = data_to_load.tbl_id
)
-- Insert the non-existing
INSERT INTO
    tbl
    (tbl_id, payload)
SELECT
    tbl_id, payload
FROM
    data_to_load
WHERE
    data_to_load.tbl_id NOT IN (SELECT tbl_id FROM tbl) ;

COMMIT TRANSACTION ;
```

You'll get the same results, as you can see at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=736d379e91089c41cc6024f821e3ae9e)*.

---

In both cases, be ready for error handling, and be prepared to retry your *transactions* if they conflict due to concurrent actions also modifying your database. Your *transactions* can be explicit (like in the second case), or *implicit*, if you have some kind of auto-commit every single `INSERT`

Comment: Very good explanation, I did a simple trick by inserting only one time and updating after. I will probably integrate your solution later